# Promise.resolve() pass callback parameters

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

How to return values from promise in this case:

```
 async foo() {
   let [error, data] = await this.promiseFoo();
 ....
 }

 promiseFoo() {
   return Promise.resolve(this.asyncFoo()).then((error, data) => 
   [error, data]);
 }
```

Getting error and data undefined inside `then()`. How can I return error and data from asyncFoo? When callback it looks like: `this.asyncFoo((error, data) => {...});`

But I what to avoid using callback this time.

Comment: `asyncFoo` takes the callback as an **argument**. You might be interested in `promisify` found in libraries like Bluebird. Alternatively, create a wrapper for asyncFoo which creates a new Promise.

Comment: A promise never resolves with *both* an error and a result. Why would you want to return them as a pair? Why not use the normal `try { let data = await  this.asyncFoo(); … } catch(error) { … }`?

Comment: it's necessary for business logic to return both error and data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
promiseFoo() {
    return this.asyncFoo().then(data => [null, data], error => [error, null]);
}
```

Comment: well your answer was right if he wanted to do try catch but he want to get the error as a resolve and not as catch

Comment: @AmitWagner The onrejected handler fulfills the returned promise as well? The code does pretty much the same as your answer but is safer, simpler, shorter and more efficient.

Comment: i checked what you said and its works great. to bad i didn't know that before. could have saved some code writing  good tip(:

Comment: @AmitWagner See the [difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) for details

Answer (score 0):

try change your promiseFoo to

```js
promiseFoo() {
   return new Promise ((resolve,reject) =>{
     asyncFoo()
     .then( data =>{
        resolve([null, data])
     }  )
     .catch(err =>{
        resolve([err,null])
     })
   })
 }
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!